# Return meaningful errors in API using CQRS pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, mediator, mediatr

When using the Mediatr pattern I find quite challenging to return meaningful errors to an API controller. Let's take the `OrdersController.CancelOrder` method as an example ([src](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Controllers/OrdersController.cs)).

In this example, they "only" return `Ok()` and `BadRequest()`. In that case how will they return errors like "This orderid does not exist" (404) OR "this order has been shipped" (400) (...).

We could introduce a new class called `Result` holding both the returned values (if any) and potentially error messages. In that case, all your commands, queries should return `Result<YourModel>`. We could also add the code directly inside the controller. I cannot make up my mind both solutions have pros and cons.

What do you think about that?

Thx
Seb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly how I tend to do it using Mediatr.
Return a wrapper class.

If we take the eShopOnContainers example `CancelOrder` example, I would have the command, return a `CancelOrderCommandResult`

```
public class CancelOrderCommand : IRequest<CancelOrderCommandResult>
{ }
```

The `CancelOrderCommandResult` could be something along these lines:

```
public class CancelOrderCommandResult
{
    public CancelOrderCommandResult(IEnumerable<Error> errors)
    {
        Success = false;
        Errors = errors;
    }

    public CancelOrderCommandResult(bool success)
    {
        Success = success;
    }

    public bool Success {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<Error> Errors {get; set;}
}
```

I've omitted the `Error` class, but it could just be POCO containing the error information, error code etc...

Our handler then becomes

```
public class CancelOrderCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CancelOrderCommand, CancelOrderCommandResult>
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

    public CancelOrderCommandHandler(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(CancelOrderCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var orderToUpdate = await _orderRepository.GetAsync(command.OrderNumber);

        if(orderToUpdate == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try 
        {
            orderToUpdate.SetCancelledStatus();
            await _orderRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveEntitiesAsync();

            //iff success, return true
            return new CancelOrderCommandResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errors = MapErrorsFromException(ex);
            return new CancelOrderCommandResult(errors)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, `MapErrorsFromException` is omitted for brevity, but you could even inject this as a dependency.

In your controller, when you call `_mediator.Send` you now get back the `CancelOrderCommandResult` - and if `.Success` is true, return a 200 as before.

Otherwise, you have a collection of errors - with which you can make some decisions about what to return - a 400, 500, etc...

Comment: Interesting. Do you use this Result class for your queries as well? For example, _send(new GetOrderById()) returns NotFound or something else.

Comment: Yes, that'd be a good way to go. An alternative to this is to throw exceptions in your handler, but that goes against `don't use exceptions for flow control` a bit.

Comment: Would it be wise to return Task<ActionResult> from the command? That way you can do return NotFound(); etc...

Comment: @axelrotter No, because then you couple ASP.Net with your application layer. Every part of the system should take care of its own responsibilities.

Comment: Well then I don't see any way around making your own abstraction layer (middleware) that translates your exceptions into http errors. You can use base classes to identify which exceptions you get.